# autosys job is triggered twice from servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, autosys

our application is triggering autosys job twice from servlet. the job is scheduled to run on monday to saturday, during 4 pm. but sometimes the job is triggered twice and getting null pointer exception to the customer.(the job is not triggered twice all day, it happens infrequently, like 2 days in a scheduled week)

while checking autosys logs, we didnt get any clue for the job getting triggered twice. but on customer side, it is logged.

what are all the possiblilities for a job to be triggered twice? while analysing we got exceptions like, http post Connection error ,time out and overlap (in time-excluded!).
but not sure what type of issue causing this.

any clues, pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the parent box met its dependency, the box triggered and started running (there will be latency between Active state and Running state).
Before it could move on to running state, the child job is triggered if it don’t have any other dependency.
And once the job box moved to running state, will kick-off the child job again.
It can be deduced by comparing the starting time and processed time.

I saw a real-time example: box started at 10.00.00 and processed time 10.00.45.
Child job started and 10.00.15 and completed in 10.00.32. It kicks off again after 10.00.45

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are saying is that the Autosys log show that the job is only ran once, but the application log shows that the command it runs occurse twice. If that is true, focus your effort on the application side. In 10+ years running Autosys in a very large shop, I can't remember any occurance of Autosys running a command without logging something in the log. Not saying that can't happen, but the great majority of the times I have investigated the same issue, the problem was on the application side.